# How refresh/update @Autowired EurekaClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I started a couple of months ago to study Spring for work, and I'm creating an architecture with Netflix Zuul and Netflix Eureka.

I wasn't able to implement Hystrix Fallback when apps are deployed on Tomcat, so I decided to use the EurekaClient and RouteLocator beans.

They work very well, but when an app falls and is no more registered on Eureka server, obviously EurekaClient bean is not updated with this fallen, so if I search the app with the method getApplications() it's still there.

How can I do to refresh/update EurekaClient bean? Is it possible?

This is the first time that i make a question on stack overflow and I still don't know how to post the code, so I hope my question is sufficient, otherwise I'll try to post it somehow.

```
public class Prefilter extends ZuulFilter

   @Autowired
   EurekaClient eurekaClient;

   @Autowired
   RouteLocator routeLocator;

   // some methods of zuul filter


   @Override
   public Object run() {
      RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
      HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();

      String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

      for(Route route : routeLocator.getRoutes()) {
          if(requestURI.contains(route.getFullPath.substring(0, route.getFullPath().lenght() - 2))) {
              if(eurekaClient.getApplication(route.getId() == null)) {
                  return "Service offline, retry later";
              }
          }
      }

      return null;
   }
```

I have added only the main part of my code. As you can see when the pre filter is called for the first time it initialize the EurekaClient bean with a certain number of services registered on eureka server.

If, after a certain amount of time a service falls down, the eurekaClient variable is not updated, and the for cycle, when arrives to check if eurekaClient.getApplication(etc...) == null it returns false, because for the variable the service is still up.

How can I do to resolve this problem?

I apologize in advance for my English, it's quite horrible.

Comment: You can include code fragments, which is very appreciated, by including them in single backticks like `var a = 3;` or indent them with four spaces or use the code sample button in the editor, also available via `CTRL-K`. You can also always consult the question mark in the upper right corner of the text editor when asking or editing questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring Cloud Netflix **Hystrix** has depencency on Netflix **Ribbon** load balancer and Ribblon client has an in-memory **cache** for registered services with Eureka Server.

The cache is updated when the requested service is not available , which will have to call the server again.

I think you should call the service to update the cache.